# How to create dummy module of add to cart?

Tags: magento-1.9, module, addtocart

I am trying to create dummy module of add to cart. but i am not getting all file path. those who know complete add to cart button module with shopping cart file path please specify complete module...

Comment: add to cart is default in magento why you want to create dummy module what you want to include ? Please specify.

Comment: because i want to to create add to quote module same like this module

Comment: i need only add to quote button like add to cart. after that it will be show in quotation link with quantity like shopping cart. so i need only product list quotation.

Comment: finally i want to export this list as a pdf or print.

Comment: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/b2b-cart-quote.html you checkout this extension it may help you help you.

Comment: https://www.cart2quote.com/magento-cart2quote-trial.html

Comment: this is chargeable plugin.

Comment: anybody knows complete module please share.